# Spring Cloud Config, how to fetch binary files from git repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

Spring `cloud-config-server` has a built in mechanism to communicate with git repository and read files which are stored there. Then `cloud-config-server` also has built in mechanism to expose endpoints to clients (normally spring boot apps) which can read those files and use them as configurations.

This is well documented in spring documentation as can be seen from bellow.

According to [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_spring_cloud_config_server)

> Spring Cloud Config Server
>
> Spring Cloud Config Server provides an HTTP
> resource-based API for external configuration (name-value pairs or
> equivalent YAML content).

Also as [documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_serving_alternative_formats) about the serving format

> Serving Alternative Formats
>
> The default JSON format from the
> environment endpoints is perfect for consumption by Spring
> applications, because it maps directly onto the Environment
> abstraction. If you prefer, you can consume the same data as YAML or
> Java properties by adding a suffix (".yml", ".yaml" or ".properties")
> to the resource path. This can be useful for consumption by
> applications that do not care about the structure of the JSON
> endpoints or the extra metadata they provide (for example, an
> application that is not using Spring might benefit from the simplicity
> of this approach).

It can [also](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_serving_plain_text) support txt format

> Serving Plain Text
>
> Instead of using the Environment abstraction (or
> one of the alternative representations of it in YAML or properties
> format), your applications might need generic plain-text configuration
> files that are tailored to their environment.

But considering that spring cloud config server has the built in mechanism to communicate with a git repository and also exposes endpoints to the clients to consume the delivered files, it would make sense for other type of files to be able to be served from those endpoints as well.

It could be for example `.pdf` , `.xslx` , or even `.zip`

For example let's assume that the configured git repository contains the file `myFile.zip` in `featureA` branch. Then the call under the exposed path of type `/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]` for example as
`serverUrl:serverPort/myApp/default/featureA/myFile.zip` is able to deliver the file but is always delivered as raw `.txt` file which then corrupts the content of the original file existing in git.

I have already found the solution, but invested many hours on it and it was strange that it was not  documented in spring documentation. So it is probably good to exist here as well to spare some time from others having the same issue.

Comment: Git and Java aren't particularly relevant here: you just have to convince the server that binary data are allowed, as you've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed under [this](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/926) issue, `spring-cloud-config-server` runs under the hood with the help of a normal `spring-boot` app. Considering that `spring-boot` has built in content negotiation mechanism it is able to consume and produce different content as well.

As for `spring-cloud-config-server` it is possible to fetch binary files from git as well as other files (ex zip, pdf, word, xlsx ...) if the call is made with the header **`Accept: application/octet-stream`**  . This way the call to `serverUrl:serverPort/myApp/default/featureA/myFile.zip` is able to deliver a copy of the original file `myFile.zip` without any corruption.